# Best practice SQL запросов в коде

Tags: python, sql, best-practice

SQL запросы в python. Как лучше? Так:

```
def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status=True):
    """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO subscriptions (user_id, status) VALUES(?,?)",
                                       (user_id, status))
```

Или так:

```
INSERT_INTO_SUBSCRIPTION = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (user_id, status) VALUES(?,?)"    
def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status=True):
    """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute(INSERT_INTO_SUBSCRIPTION, (user_id, status))
```

А если запрос на несколько десятков строк и таких запросов много, то не удобно держать эти запросы в переменной или внутри ф-ии. Создавать отдельный файлы для запросов? Какой best practice в данной теме?

Comment: В любом случае хардкод запроса (вариант 1) - это wrong practice. ОСОБЕННО если запрос - некое многоэтажное безобразие. IMCO отлаженные запросы следует конвертировать в хранимые процедуры и выносить на сервер.

Comment: @Akina а код самих хранимых процедур держать в отдельном каталоге проекта? в таком случае нужно будет разрабатывать миграцию, которая будет накатывать хранимки в БД. Потенциальные дополнительные баги. Хотя подход вполне годный - можно создать метод, который будет вызывать хранимку и передавать ей параметры. Спасибо. Подумаю над этим

Comment: *в таком случае нужно будет разрабатывать миграцию, которая будет накатывать хранимки в БД.* Так это ж один раз. Сравниваем версию на сервере и в файле данных, при несовпадении - дропаем БД с процедурами и создаём заново. А потом только файл данных переписывать...

Comment: @Akina не совсем один раз :) сервисам свойственно улучшение. Тем более баги никто не отменял